# Callback Query is None Type in python-telegram-bot v20.7

Tags: python-telegram-bot

This is my code:

```
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, CallbackQuery
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import filters, MessageHandler, ContextTypes, ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

async def hello_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Press me", callback_data='hello')]

    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    await update.message.reply_text('Press:', reply_markup=reply_markup)

async def button_pressed(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    if query.data == 'hello':
        await query.edit_message_text("Hello!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('hello', hello_command))
    app.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(callback=button_pressed))
    app.run_polling(0)
```

The problem is that when I press the button nothing happens, although the bot should reply with "Hello!" text. I tried a lot of different options for handling callback data, but still did not make it work. During debugging process I came to conclusion that my code does not produce expected result because CallbackQuery is NoneType. That is strange because I initialise callback_data correctly. Also I found out that when code is running it never enters button_pressed function. What should I do to make my code work?

Comment: Hi. Please extend your code example so that we can actually run it to reproduce thi issue. This includes missing imports and most importantly the definition of `BUTTON`.

Comment: of course! done it. I changed BUTTON to 'hello' and added imports

Comment: The example works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Well, unfortunately  it does not work for me. I still get a NoneTypeError on CallbackQuery. I thought that there may be a problem in version of python-telegram-bot that I am using, but it is up to date

Comment: Please show the traceback, then. Make sure that the code that you show here in the question is exactly the same one that produces the error. Please also post the output of `python -m telegram`.

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem while trying to implement menu buttons

Answer (score 0):

Hello there I reproduced it. If it was what u gave was actually the full code there were some import issues I fixed them and made it more concise and readable and u don't need that await query answer part though it is fine if u add it as answer in obviously none so doesn't matter though it was unnecessary. Your code works as u have there were just adjusting need to be done and imports need to be added. **[link][https://pastebin.com/20XNqeZg]**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35510390)